# Add Class to body tag when PHP finds a word within a web page

Tags: php, html, joomla

I am trying to add a class to the body tag when php finds a certain word within a bit of html code.

So far I have come up with:

```
<?php echo $this->row->description;
if (stripos($this->row->description, 'Sold')!== false) {
    echo 'true';  
} 
?>
```

I can see the 'true' being echoed on the web page. So I know it's working and it doesn't show if the word 'sold' is not on the web page.

What I want to do is change echo 'true'; to something that adds the class 'true' to the body tag of the web page.

Comment: You can do something like `$append_to_body = 'true';`, then in your body tag add `class="<?php echo $append_to_body?>"`

Comment: Is not clear what you want, but @scrowler is right

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
<body class="<?php echo stripos($this->row->description, 'Sold')!==false?'true':'' ?>">
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (I tried to use it as an ID not a class), it just left "" in the body tag. You can see it here: [estate.marketingagencyleeds.co.uk/search-for-a-property/1-student-property-close-to-university](http://estate.marketingagencyleeds.co.uk/search-for-a-property/1-student-property-close-to-university)

Comment: @simon it's blank `''` because the `if` evaluates to `FALSE`

Comment: @Simon: In this case it will be empty is Sold is not found. You get the description before to print the body tag right?